# Stricter type-check on JS builtin functions

Tags: typescript

TypeScript is trying to be compliant with ECMAScript spec and thus allows loose typing on builtin functions, eg.,: `Number.isFinite` is accepting `any`, not only numbers.

Now, this behaviour unfortunately already lead to several errors in our codebase that were missed by the type-check. Is there an easy way to either:

- make the type signatures for builtin functions more strict
- or, disallow usage of built-in JavaScript functions by linter

Or, do you have any other ideas how to tackle this issue?

Comment: You may be intrigued by Matt Pocock's TypeScript Reset project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **stricter parameters**, try to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) like this:

```
// put in some d.ts
declare global {
  interface NumberConstructor {
    isFinite<T>(value: T): T extends number ? boolean : void
    // isFinite(value: number): boolean
  }
}

export {}
```

I just "break" the return type of function `isFinite` when the parameter type is not correct. So you will see some errors when you using the return value.

Note that if you declare a function like what I commented, it will just fallback to build-in definition.

---

And in my case, usually I want the **return type** stricter, so It can be done like this:

```
// put in some d.ts
declare global {
  interface NumberConstructor {
    isFinite(value: unknown): value is number
  }
}

export {}
```

Note that the *fallback behavior* in this case still exist.